# How/should I use nested for loops inside of if statements?

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, for-loop

I was hoping to get some help from someone who is better than me with using Objective C and Xcode.

I am using an example project and trying to figure out exactly what it's asking me to do and how to do it. It is specifically asking me:

> STEP 1: Use the if statement below to determine if defaults contains a bool value of "TRUE" for a key called "registered"

This snippet is what I have so far for this problem:

```
if (self.defaults == YES)
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(goToLogin)];
}
```

The "for" and "if" are both bold in the directions, leading me to believe I need to use both.

Edit: This is more of the surrounding code because of the comments suggesting I didn't upload all of the necessary code.

```
#import "RegistrationViewController.h"

@interface RegistrationViewController ()

@end

@implementation RegistrationViewController

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:TRUE];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.textFields = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:_emailTextField,_userNameTextField,_passwordTextField,_confirmPasswordText    Field, nil];

 defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

//STEP 1: Use the if statement below to determine if defaults contains a bool value of     "TRUE" for a key called "registered"
if (self.defaults == YES)
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(goToLogin)];
}
}
```

I am really new to this and just don't know where to go from here! any help would be very appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
FMM92

Comment: we miss context, but you definitely want to check out `NSUserDefaults`

Comment: How is `defaults` defined? The description makes it sound like some sort of dictionary since you are supposed to access the "registered" key and see if its value is true.

Comment: need more information about this "for" statement your asking about and what you should be looping through.

Comment: That "snippet" has nothing to do with the text around it.

Comment: How would you do the problem if you were writing down the instructions for your dumb partner to do it, with only pencil and paper??  Forget about loops and if statements and figure out how to solve the problem conceptually.  Then map those concepts to whatever statements you need.

Comment: (The first step in learning to program is to forget about programming.)

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to tell the precise situation here, but this is how it sounds to me:

`defaults` is almost certainly meant to be an instance of [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html). The bolded "for" in your instructions is not suggesting a for-loop; it's giving you a hint at the method you need to use. Take a look at the NSUserDefaults reference there and see if you can find a method that might be useful for looking up a BOOL value for a named key.

Comment: When you say find a method that mgiht be useful, are you saying  I am to write a method inside of the     if (self.defaults == YES)
if statement? So I am  going to declare a new key, and then set the key as "YES" if the self.defaults == YES?